# How to reset motion with a button click in UPBGE?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am working on a game where you can zoom in and out with the camera (which is linked to a character controller) using the mouse wheel. Would it be possible to reset the camera to the starting position by clicking the middle mouse button (i.e. undo the motion)? This is to make it more convenient when players zoom too far in or out.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is about UpBGE, not Blender

Comment: Apparently you solved the issue on a duplicate thread: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-reset-motion-with-a-button-click-in-upbge/1321897